# Delegating just scroll events in UICollectionView inside ScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I have a **ABCController** that including **UIPageViewController** and this controller including 3 different controllers that connected to tabs.

In **first controller** that connect to **UIPageViewController** there is **CollectionView** that delegated to it's own controller and I'm using of **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** to shape cells.

But when I change delegate controller in **ABCController** to it self (to make syncScroll with mainScroll)

**func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize**

stops working because I delegated collectionview to another controller.

Is there any way to just delegate scroll events to another controller?

I know that it may little complex but I hope to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it by create a wrapper:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDatasource {
    var scrollDelegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?

    // delegate scroll events
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       scrollDelegate?.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
    }
    
    // other events
}
```